# Retrieving UIImage from video only when function completed creating them - swift - swift programmatically

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset, avassetimagegenerator

I'm creating `UIImages` from video using `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes` :

```
fileprivate func createImageFramesFromVideo(completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
    guard let url = self.videoUrl else {
        return
    }
    
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    let videoDuration = asset.duration
    
    //getting image snapshots more or less in half the video
    let time1 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/10, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time2 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/11, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time3 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/12, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time4 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time5 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/12, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time6 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/11, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time7 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/10, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    
    var imageArray : [UIImage] = []
    
    imageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: [NSValue(time: time1), NSValue(time: time2), NSValue(time: time3), NSValue(time: time4), NSValue(time: time5), NSValue(time: time6), NSValue(time: time7)]) { (time, image, time1, result, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("there's an error in retrieving the images", err)
        }
       
        let theImage = UIImage(cgImage: image!)
        
        imageArray.append(theImage)
        
        if(result == .succeeded){
            completion(imageArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Since the completion handler of the function is called **each time** a new image is created, `completion()` is called multiple times.

I want to achieve that `completion()` is called only after all the images (in this case 7) are created.
How can I do it?

Comment: You can use a `DispatchQueue` for that, with a `enter()` `leave()`, or since you might know how many images it will be generated, you can check the count of `imageArray`, no?

Comment: Great idea, didn't think about it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `DispatchGroup` to wait for several async functions to complete. You need to make sure your calls to `DispatchGroup.enter()` and `leave()` are balanced (called the same number of times), since when you use `dispatchGroup.notify(queue:)`, the closure will only be executed once `leave()` has been called for each `enter()`.

You need to call `enter` for each element of your `times` array (which will contain the `CMTime` variables `time1` to `time7`, then in the completion block of `generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes:`, you call `leave()`. This ensures that the `notify(queue:)` will only execute its closure once `generateCGImagesAsynchronously` called its own completion for all images.

```
fileprivate func createImageFramesFromVideo(completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
    guard let url = self.videoUrl else { return }

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    let videoDuration = asset.duration

    //getting image snapshots more or less in half the video
    let time1 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/10, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time2 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/11, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time3 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 - videoDuration.value/12, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time4 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time5 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/12, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time6 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/11, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let time7 = CMTime(value: videoDuration.value/2 + videoDuration.value/10, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let times = [NSValue(time: time1), NSValue(time: time2), NSValue(time: time3), NSValue(time: time4), NSValue(time: time5), NSValue(time: time6), NSValue(time: time7)]

    var imageArray : [UIImage] = []

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    times.forEach { _ in
        dispatchGroup.enter()
    }


    imageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: times) { (time, image, time1, result, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("there's an error in retrieving the images", err)
        }

        let theImage = UIImage(cgImage: image!)

        imageArray.append(theImage)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(imageArray)
    }
}
```